# onclick event on dropdown is not getting called

Tags: javascript, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am adding following Combobox "Select Page " dynamically to jsp page, which on change populates another combobox called "Objects".Select Page dropdown is loading properly with content but its not triggering the event on it. i.e. populateObjects. I have kept alert in populateObjects() function, which shows that its not even invoking this alert. Please help.

```
//Select Page
       var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
       var element4 = document.createElement("select");
       element4.setAttribute('id', 'selPageRow' + rowCount);
       element4.setAttribute('name', 'selPageRow' + rowCount);
       element4.setAttribute('onClick', 'javascript:populateObjects(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML,'+rowCount+');');
       var PageArray = getPages();
       var option = document.createElement("option");
       option.text = "Select..."; 
       option.value = "select"; 
       element4.options.add(option);
       for(var i=0;i<PageArray.length;i++)
           {
               var option = document.createElement("option");
               option.text = PageArray[i].attributes[0].nodeValue; 
               option.value = PageArray[i].attributes[0].nodeValue;  
               element4.options.add(option);
           }
       cell4.appendChild(element4); 

// Code for populating Object dropdown

    function populateObjects(selectedValue,rowCount)
    {
        alert(selectedValue);
        var SelBox = document.getElementById('selObjRow' + rowCount);
        removeAllOptions(SelBox);
        var ObjArry = getObjects(selectedValue);

        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = "Select..."; 
        option.value = "select"; 
        SelBox.options.add(option);
        if(ObjArry.length>0)
        {
            for(var i=0;i<ObjArry.length;i++)
               {
                   var option = document.createElement("option");
                   option.text = ObjArry[i].attributes[0].nodeValue; 
                   option.value = ObjArry[i].attributes[0].nodeValue;  
                   SelBox.options.add(option);
               }
        }
        else
        {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = "None"; 
            option.value = "none"; 
            SelBox.options.add(option);
        }
        cell5.appendChild(SelBox);
    }
```

Comment: please provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code

Comment: I m sorry but what is this fiddle?

Comment: Where is `rowCount` set? From what I can see, you never define it.

Comment: Ok, Let me be more clear on my problem. This code works on my friend's system for populationg objects on change of Select page.Whereas its not working for me despite both having same IE versions. Is there any tweak in IE settings to make javascript work?

Comment: I took  your code and pasted it into the `JavaScript` part of a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWjzS/), but I get an error: "row is not defined". Could you make a fiddle that contains code that is runnable, so that we can hack with it and make it work as you want?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `onClick` event to `onChange` event

```
   element4.setAttribute('onChange', 'javascript:populateObjects(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML,'+rowCount+');');
```